# I keep getting Nonetype but I dont think I should be?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy-flask for my projects as well as json module.

I have two classes I'm pulling data from.

The two data types are Ints and List (I made sure of this by using type).  When I try to append the int to the list I get None. Whats wrong?

```
def update_retweet_count(TWEET, TWEET_has_retweet):

    if type(json.loads(TWEET_has_retweet.js_rt)) != list:
        list_of_retweets = list([0])
    else:
        list_of_retweets = list(json.loads(TWEET_has_retweet.js_rt))

    new_rtc = int(TWEET.tmp_rt_count)

    x = list_of_retweets.append(new_rtc)
    print x
```

When I run above X is None.

4 Hours later I try this below and It works!

```
def update_retweet_count(TWEET, TWEET_has_retweet):
    if type(json.loads(TWEET_has_retweet.js_rt)) != list:
        list_of_retweets = list([0])
    else:
        list_of_retweets = list(json.loads(TWEET_has_retweet.js_rt))

    lst =[]

    new_rtc = int(TWEET.tmp_rt_count)

    [lst.append(y) for y in list_of_retweets]

    lst.append(new_rtc)

    print lst
```

Why does the first code not work?

Thank you!

Fernando

Comment: A couple comments:  1) `list([0])` is the same as just `[0]`.  2) you could probably just do `lst = list_of_retweets`, or at worst `lst = list(list_of_retweets)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.append` always returns `None`: it changes the list *in place*. You do:

```
x = list_of_retweets.append(new_rtc)
print x
```

in the first example and:

```
lst.append(new_rtc)
print lst
```

in the second (correct) example.

Comment: @mgilson: FGITW, but you'll outdraw me next time. (Incidentally, is "Argv" what programmers say when they're frustrated?)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that somewhere, and thought it was funny, so I've started saying it...